# Dynamically passing PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to accomplish a JavaScript form that will load the result from a PHP request on an external website, after a text box is filled out.

Right now, I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript"/>
function sendrequest() {
document.location="myphpsite.com/submit.php?tb="+document.getElementById("tb").value;
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="tb" onChange="sendrequest()" />
</form>
```

This code is going nowhere, because from my current knowledge, you can only load PHP variables on startup, by using "script src=... ", and by having the php page return some javascript code.

What I'm looking for is a way to request/receive php variables dynamically, something that would work like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getdata() {
return document.get("myphpsite.com/submit.php?tb=hi");
}
</script>
```

In other words, is there a function that dynamically "reads" a website, and returns the raw text?

Comment: You want to hear about [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

You should go read this and then read it again, AJAX is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

best example with PHP and AJAX -

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp